# Basic Bash array question

Tags: bash, variable, array, echo

```
#!/bin/bash
# query1.sh

numbers=(53 8 12 9 784 69)
echo ${numbers[3]} # <--- this echoes "9" to standard output.

number=numbers[3]
echo number # <--- this echoes "number" to stdout.
echo $number # <--- this echoes "numbers[3]" to stdout.
echo ... <--- ???
```

What syntax should I use to echo the variable named `number` and get "9" as the standard output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's where you want variable indirection using the  `${!var}` operator:

```
bash-4.4$ numbers=(53 8 12 9 784 69)
bash-4.4$ number=numbers[3]
bash-4.4$ echo "${!number}"
9
```

The `zsh` equivalent would be:

```
numbers=(53 8 12 9 784 69)
number=numbers[4]
echo ${(P)number}
```

(`zsh` arrays indices start at 1 like in most other shells and shell tools, so you can use `numbers[4]` to get the 4th number).

If you wanted to assign the value of 4th element of the array to `$number`, you'd do `number=$numbers[4]` in `zsh`, or `number=${numbers[3]}` in `ksh` (and `bash` which just copied `ksh` arrays).

Comment: Sure, it _can_ be done by using indirection, but I wouldn't go as far as to say that it's what the OP _wants_. It seems more reasonable to expect that what they want is the correct syntax to get the element `9` directly, whereas this is more like a workaround for their incorrect guess.

Comment: @Tom, that would be the last part of the answer. But it looks like they known already how to get the value of an element of the array (`echo ${numbers[3]}` in the question).

Comment: Yeah, good point. My understanding was that they hadn't worked out that they could assign `${numbers[3]}` to another variable.

Comment: @Stéphane: Many thanks. Further to this: What if the array's index is a variable (let's say `$i`, where i=3)? The syntax has to change again..

Comment: @AnthonyWebber, the array index is taken as an arithmetic expression, so you can use `numbers[i]`.

Comment: @Stéphane: OK! Brilliant:) I like that both `$i` and `i` work there. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that this:

```
number=numbers[3]
```

Is not assigning the 4th element of the array `numbers` to the variable `number`. That's because `numbers[3]` doesn't actually mean anything:

```
$ numbers=(53 8 12 9 784 69)
$ echo $numbers[3]
53[3]
```

What happens is that when you use the name of the array alone as a variable, what is actually being used is the first element of the array (`53`). So `$numbers[3]` becomes `53[3]`. What you want is:

```
$ number=${numbers[3]}
$ echo $number
9
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable, you don't need to use the `$`, but when you use it, you should.

So just assign like this, and it should works 
`number=${numbers[3]}`

Comment: That won't and doesn't work, and isn't what I asked. But I appreciate you answering.

Comment: Yep, i made a mistake in the syntax. I corrected it.